# Prolog: Convert list into dictionary?

Tags: list, dictionary, prolog, type-conversion

I am searching some swi-prolog predicate:

```
list_to_dict(List, Dict) :- ??
```

Which is able to convert a list like

```
l = [a, b, c, d]
```

into a Prolog [dict](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts) `d` whose keys are equal to the list indexes starting at 1.  In this example above `d` is of form:

```
d = dict_label{1:a,2:b,3:c,4:d}
```

I would appreciate, if you can help me to find some general and hopefully short solution of that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following predicate:

```
% list_to_dict(+Values, +Tag, -Dict)

  list_to_dict(Values, Tag, Dict) :-
      findall(Key-Value, nth1(Key, Values, Value), Pairs),
      dict_create(Dict, Tag, Pairs).
```

Example:

```
?- list_to_dict([a,b,c,d], dict_label, Dict).
Dict = dict_label{1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d}.
```